# How can I inject a reference into another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm trying to make a text game library in Python called Tega. In the game engine, the world is made up of a traversible graph of nodes, linked together with node connections. The module contains subclasses for nodes, objects, and node connections, which are utilized like this:

```
class room1(tega.Node):
    base_description = "You are standing in a node."

room1 = room1(name="room1")

class room2(tega.Node):
    base_description = "You are standing in a different node."

room2 = room2(name="room2")

class object(tega.Object):
    pass

object1 = object(location = "room1")

class connection(tega.Node_Connection):
    pass

connection1 = connection(room1, room2)

engine = tega.GameEngine(nodes=[room1, room2], objects=[object1], node_connections=[connection1], starting_node = room1)
```

My question concerns the code for the node connections. I had this brilliant idea to make the node_connection class "inject" a reference to itself into the nodes it referenced. This would make lots of things in the game engine easier to code. My code to do that looks like this:

```
class connection(tega.Node_Connection):
    def __init__(self, node1, node2):
        self.node1 = node1
        self.node2 = node2
    self.node1.connections["north"] = self
    self.node2.connections["south"] = self
```

But every time I run that, it gives me a `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.

I'm not sure why that syntax doesn't work. But then again, I'm not sure that what I'm trying to do is very Pythonic in the first place.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong... you've indented `self.node1.connections['north'] = self` **outside** `__init__`.

Comment: "But every time I run that, it gives me a NameError: name 'self' is not defined." Notice how you *don't* get that error for the previous line `self.node2 = node2`, even though you are still using `self`? Other than the actual code on that line, can you think of something different about it? For example, the context that it's in?

Comment: Oooooh, dumb question. Sorry! I honestly didn't consider that it was an indentation error.